# Can you please put my question on hold while I edit the question body and fiddle?

Tags: support, specific-question

If it is OK to put [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125864/how-to-write-code-that-can-be-applied-to-various-sections-of-a-website-using-ful) on hold while I edit the question body and most of all the code/fiddle that comes with it to better reflect what I am trying to ask or get out of it, that would be great, thank you.

I have unfortunately not had the time to do this recently (edit the question and code) but will surly have to come back to this question as I need a good answer. For this some parts of my code here have to be rewritten and more explaining on the code that is present through fullPage.js has to be done.

Basically I am hooking into fullPage.js functionality without changing the fullPage.js source and at the moment this is still quite messy. For this to not get more convoluted I will take more time.

I basically asked the question too early into the development process, some logic is not right and now there is an answer and obvious downvotes, efforts from people that could have been spent better if the question would be on hold.

If putting the question on hold for this reason is not possible then it would be nice if some other sort of measure could be taken to make people understand that at this stage the question is not ready to be answered.

In fact, is it possible to delete the whole question (and possibly also get rid of the downvotes) or is it better to edit the question and code but leave it in some sort of "pause" status for now? I don't mind too much about the downvotes, totally accepted in this case, just don't want to aggregate more downvotes since the question as it is now is not complete and is going to get a major re-work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no upvoted answer on your question, you should be able to delete it yourself - just post a new question when you're ready.

Comment: Deleted and thank you.